# In swift, how to download a json file from storage in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, storage, nsdata

I create a function to download a json file from urlLink in the storage of Firestore.
Here it is:

```
func chargerLObjetDeFirestore(urlLink: String, completion: @escaping (_ menuObject: MenuObjectPartager?) -> Void) {
        if urlLink != "" {
            let documentUrl = URL(string: urlLink)
            let data = NSData(contentof: documentUrl!) //No exact matches in call to initializer
                if data != nil {
                    // decoding the data loaded
                    let loadedMenu: MenuObjectPartager = try data.decodedObject()
                    completion(loadedMenu)
                } else {
                    print("@@No document found in urlLink")
                    completion(nil)
                }
        }
    }
```

But i have an issue. It says: No exact matches in call to initializer
and it's about NSData line.

So, how to solve the issue about NSData when downloading a json file from an urlLink?

Comment: I know there's an accepted answer but you may be overthinking it. Files in storage are... files. It could be a .jpg, and .png, or a .txt - files uploaded to storage don't need to be encoded. So "a json file" could be one of many things but probably just a .txt file so you don't need NSData at all. Just download it using the code in the Storage documentation [Download a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_to_a_local_file). If the file was encoded before uploading, this doesn't apply but that's not really necessary either. You can simply upload a .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will be the only issue with your code but error states that there's no initializer with such params.

Correct one would be:

> NSData(contentsOf: documentUrl!)

You can check out documentation for more initializers:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init